# how to copy / install various data from a DVD drive to Hard disk in Ununtu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, dvd

I have got around 15 Nos. DVDs from a friend of mine.  These DVDs contain 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) amd64 Repository  ck contains all the 64 bit programs available in the Ubuntu repositories - main, universe, multiverse and restricted - of the Ubuntu Trusty Tahr(Ubuntu 14.04) release.

Unfortunately, being  a novice I do not know how I can install these packages from my DVD to my hard disk.

Can any one of my dear friends, kindly come up for my guidance, please.

with deep regards
Anil kumar

Comment: See this, http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$sudo apt-cdrom add
```

to add these DVD to repository list

and then use

```
$sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
$sudo apt-get install {package name}
```

Comment: How to find out the Package name?